# SQL Server Script shortcuts

Tags: sql-server

I have numerous scripts to run in SQL Server.

Currently I've made many scripts which have been saved as file and can be loaded in SSMS when needed.

I want to know if we have any shortcut(bookmark) in SQL server to script files.

So far I've found nothing on internet. (note that creating stored procedures for these ad-hoc scripts is not an option)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're hoping for here.   What would you want this shortcut to do?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlchicken_coop/archive/2014/11/06/using-bookmarks-in-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By pressing `Cntrl+K, Cntrl+W` combination you can see the Bookmark manager.

Here you can see all bookmarks in locally saved sql queries.

Like in the below screenshot I have a bookmark for `getLocationBasedMemberVisitsData.Sql`file.

[image]

**On how to add a bookmark**

goto `Edit>Bookmarks>toggle bookmark` when you are inside your file with your edit cursor at the line you want to bookmark

**P.S.:** You can also create a folder hierarchy much like in browsers like Chrome

Store all needed files inside a single solution. Call it `Utilities`. Much like VS you can browse through the solution files using Solution explorer.

**Caveat:** The bookmarks on loose sql files are not persisted. So on a restart(close/open) for SSMS tool these are lost.

If you do need to persist bookmarks, create bound files i.e. store the files in a solution first.

Also the bookmarks in Management Studio are consist with Visual Studio.

**Addendum:**

Based on asker's comment

> This just bookmark a line on a script. Is these any way to give these bookmarks a name?

You can rename both the folders as well as bookmark name by double clicking on it or by `right click>rename` option

On another comment

> What do you mean by saving as as solution. I cannot find such option in SSMS. Are you referring to VS?

SQL server management studio like VS supports creation of Solutions(project) which are essentially collection of related queries/SP with connection information and other needed stuff.

To create a new solution press `cntrl+shift+N`. see screen shot below
[image]

Any bookmarks on solution files are sticky. Next time you open the solutions, bookmarks are presented back to you.

The SQL solution can be opened in VS too. The bookmark information along with other user information is stored in a `*.ssms_suo` file much like a `*.suo` file of VS.

It is a good idea to store all helpful files in a utilities solution which can be open all the time so that you can easily access it.

Comment: @SNash As I said in my answer in the Caveat. The Bookmarks are not persisted unless they are part of a solution :/ Save the scripts as part of a solution and bookmark them too on critical parts of scripts. You'll never lose them

Answer (score 1):

I think a Snippet is what you are asking for:

> A Transact-SQL.code snippet is a template containing the basic
>   structure of a Transact-SQL statement or block. You can use snippets
>   as a starting point when adding statements in the Database Engine
>   Query Editor. You can insert the pre-defined snippets supplied with
>   SQL Server, or create your own.

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878440.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio you could use menu -> Tools -> External Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SQL Prompt? If so, this has a Tab History feature that lets you search for query windows, regardless of whether they have been saved or not.

If not, I'd use the snipppet feature that VV5198722 has referred to, or the Template Browser (invoked from the view menu).